# Find duplicates in a list of tuples

Tags: python, algorithm, list, duplicates, tuples

You are given information about users of your website. The information includes username, a phone number and/or an email. Write a program that takes in a list of tuples where each tuple represents information for a particular user and returns a list of lists where each sublist contains the indices of tuples containing information about the same person. For example:

```
Input:
[("MLGuy42", "andrew@example.com", "123-4567"),
("CS229DungeonMaster", "123-4567", "ml@example.net"),
("Doomguy", "john@example.org", "carmack@example.com"),
("andrew26", "andrew@example.com", "mlguy@example.com")]

Output:
[[0, 1, 3], [2]]
```

Since "MLGuy42", "CS229DungeonMaster" and "andrew26" are all the same person.

Each sublist in the output should be sorted and the outer list should be sorted by the first element in the sublist.

---

Below is the code snippet that I did for this problem. It seems to work fine, but I'm wondering if there is a better/optimized solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
def find_duplicates(user_info):
    results = list()
    seen = dict()
    for i, user in enumerate(user_info):
        first_seen = True
        key_info = None
        for info in user:
            if info in seen:
                first_seen = False
                key_info = info
                break
        if first_seen:
            results.append([i])
            pos = len(results) - 1
        else:
            index = seen[key_info]
            results[index].append(i)
            pos = index
        for info in user:
            seen[info] = pos
    return results
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work.  Move the first line of input to the end of the input list and you get a completely different answer: `[[0], [1], [2, 3]]`

Comment: Ahhh you're right. My code does not work. DId you have a chance to find a bug?

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for your suggestion. But, I'll just leave my question in Stack Overflow because my original code has a problem/bug that needed to be fixed to get it working. From my understanding, Code Review is for working code that needs to be optimized. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've reached to an optimized working solution using a graph. Basically, I've created a graph with each node contains its user information and its index. Then, use dfs to traverse the graph and find the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can simplify this using sets:

```
from random import shuffle

def find_duplicates(user_info):

    reduced = unreduced = {frozenset(info): [i] for i, info in enumerate(user_info)}

    while reduced is unreduced or len(unreduced) > len(reduced):

        unreduced = dict(reduced)  # make a copy

        for identifiers_1, positions_1 in unreduced.items():

            for identifiers_2, positions_2 in unreduced.items():

                if identifiers_1 is identifiers_2:
                    continue

                if identifiers_1 & identifiers_2:
                    del reduced[identifiers_1], reduced[identifiers_2]
                    reduced[identifiers_1 | identifiers_2] = positions_1 + positions_2
                    break
            else:  # no break
                continue

            break

    return sorted(sorted(value) for value in reduced.values())

my_input = [ \
    ("CS229DungeonMaster", "123-4567", "ml@example.net"), \
    ("Doomguy", "john@example.org", "carmack@example.com"), \
    ("andrew26", "andrew@example.com", "mlguy@example.com"), \
    ("MLGuy42", "andrew@example.com", "123-4567"), \
]

shuffle(my_input)  # shuffle to prove order independence

print(my_input)
print(find_duplicates(my_input))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
[('CS229DungeonMaster', '123-4567', 'ml@example.net'), ('MLGuy42', 'andrew@example.com', '123-4567'), ('andrew26', 'andrew@example.com', 'mlguy@example.com'), ('Doomguy', 'john@example.org', 'carmack@example.com')]
[[0, 1, 2], [3]]
>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. It looks like your code works fine but inefficient because it breaks whenever it detects intersections and starts over again and again until there are no more intersections. I tested it with random generated integers (since it should work with integers as well), but it takes forever.
    `from random import randrange`
    `from timeit import timeit`

    `MAXVALUE = 1000`

    `for a in range(5):`
        `user_info = [[randrange(MAXVALUE) for i in range(3)] for _ in range(1000)]`
        `print(timeit(lambda: find_duplicates(user_info), number=10000))`

Comment: For 1,000 random generated user_info, it took about 687 seconds with 10000 loops.

Comment: Finally, I've got about 40 seconds for the same test condition with using a graph. Thank you for your help though!